# How should we divide our worship at night?

Tags: ramadan, tahajjud, nafl

If someone was going to spend all night in worship, hoping to obtain Laylatul Qadr, what should he do? Like should he spend all of it praying, or some of it praying, some istighfar, some duas, etc. What is the prescribed "division" for this?

Comment: "How should …" is a kind of question that attracts subjective answers which are off-topic here. I personally don't know of a specific schedule or recommendation of our prophet () and tend to say that this question will end up as opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of this night is istighfar and Tribute that ("Angels and al-Rooh descend to earth"). so all of Angels Pray for everybody that who worship and ask for forgiveness from Allah.

and one of the best ways for best of worships is '[Joshan Kabir](http://www.duas.org/downloads/JoshanKabir.pdf)' in Qadr night. you can see this [link](https://en.wikishia.net/view/Al-Jawshan_al-Kabir_Supplication) for more information about Joshan kabir.

This will bring you closer with Allah.

and As well as reciting the Holy Quran.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you should divide your worships in this way that offer some nawafil, duas, Quran recition so that you satisfied your heart. but whole night spending in praying is also good.

Comment: What's the Sunnah of worshipping at night? What did the Prophet (alaihi As-Salat wa As-Salam) do?

Answer (score 0):

As we all known every odd night may be a lyla tul qadar. 
So its better to perform 2 or 4 rakat nowafil in every night because if its laila tul qadar your 2 rakat nowafil is equall to 24 hour of prayer. 
May this will be helpful

Comment: May Allah guide us, this isn't a good advice, because you're supposed to perform nawafil everynight, in Laylatul Qadr you're supposed to worship all night.